# error c2338 C++ Standard doesn't provide a hash for this type

Tags: c++, unordered-map

So I have an unordered map in ClassA which is of type string and ClassB but when I build I get the c2338 error: The C++ Standard doesn't provide a hash for this type.

ClassA.h

```
#include <unordered_map>

class ClassB;

ClassA
{
private:
    std::unordered_map<std::string, ClassB*> map;
}
```

ClassB .h

```
class ClassB
{
private:
    size_t x, y, w, h;
    int id;
}
```

Comment: `std::hash` is specialized in the `string` header.

Comment: And `std::string` is declared in there as well, so you should be including it anyway.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem with `boost::gregorian::date`. I need a quick (& dirty) solution and I ended up using `map<boost::gregorian::date, int>` instead of `unordered_map`. Might be slower but for me it was not an issue. HTH.